# How do I disable the Cinnamon 2 lock screen?

Tags: lock-screen, cinnamon

When my computer is locked, I am presented with the default Ubuntu lockscreen. When I enter my password and unlock it, I am presented with the Cinnamon 2 lock screen and I have to enter my password again.

How can I disable the Cinnamon 2 lock screen?

Note: I've installed Cinnamon 2 with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After a bit of searching in **`dconf-editor`** (inspired by the other answers and *not* gconf), I found the schema

> org → cinnamon → desktop → lockdown

which contains a key called `disable-lock-screen`, set that to true (checked) to disable the Cinnamon lock screen.

[image: dconf-editor screenshot here]

---

#### Command Line

To turn lock screen off:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

To turn back on:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

Comment: Think those settings should be in single quotes.  +1 for edit.

Comment: oh man this killed me until I found it. Actually saw this setting but didn't grok the inverse 'set this to disable the feature'.

Comment: I found it in,

`org → mate → desktop → lockdown`

Answer (score 3):

After installing Cinnamon the way you did, and running it, opening gconf-editor, I coudn't find a cinnamon entry under desktop, only gnome.  You can disable the Gnome lock screen, and see if that helps.

[image]

Comment: It's `org/gnome/desktop/lockdown` now. Anyway, you can use the search button to look for `lockdown` if it's unlisted, and pick the most sensible one for the gnome screen.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalling `gnome-screensaver` fixed the double lock issue for me.

If you prefer the `gnome-screensaver`, as OP does, simply remove `cinnamon-screensaver` instead.

Comment: Thank you... It's truly unbelievable that we actually have to go through a check list of procedures to stop, get rid of this unwanted / annoying screensaver.

Answer (score 1):

you have to install gconf editor for that.  after install gconf editor , open it navigate as desktop - cinnamon - lockscreen or desktop - gnome - lockscreen . there you can disabled the cinnamon lock screen.

I think cinnamon using gnome lock screen.

try it.

Answer (score -2):

I installed `xscreensaver` on my system but `cinnamon-screensaver` still butts in and takes over.

An easy solution is this:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/cinnamon-screensaver /usr/bin/cinnamon-screensaver.bak
```

then:

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/screensaver
```

and add the following lines:

```
#! /bin/bash

exit 0
```

Comment: although this may solve the question, I moving/renaming binaries isn't a good solution as it bypasses the dpkg package system, which can lead to all sorts of problems. The least of which will be that on an update the old binary may be restored, leading to a re-occurrence of the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Or do this:

```
sudo chmod -wx /usr/bin/cinnamon-screensaver
```